# How would I retrieve the thumbnail image that wordpress.com RSS generates using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

I am trying to retrieve the image url that my wordpress.com RSS feed generates so I can include the image in the recent posts on my own website. I was able to use some code I found online to retrieve the other attributes but I cannot figure out how to get the image URL from the RSS.

The code I have is below:

RSS

```
<media:thumbnail url="https://mywpsite.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/iphone-01.png?w=150"/>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://mywpsite.wordpress.com/feed/');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'image' => $node->getElementsByTagName('media:thumbnail')->item(0)->nodeValue
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    $image = $feed[$x]['image'];
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    //echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Yuo should post a link to a real rss example.

Comment: I added the link to my feed that I am using in my question.

Comment: look into `xpath` and `namespaces`, there are good posts here on SO that can help to get you started.